# Undocumented LVHITTESTINFO structure LVHT flag?

Tags: listview, winapi

I am using the `LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST` message (with -1 as the `wParam` of the message) to determine which list-view item or subitem is located at a given position. I do so by testing the `flags` member of the `LVHITTESTINFO` structure.

When the mouse is over any column header controls, the `flags` member includes a seemingly undocumented value (0x00000200). Based on my observations, I would call it `LVHT_ONHEADER`.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Maybe check the WINE source and see if they've worked it out, but basically undocumented == undocumented.

Comment: Could you please explain why you use `-1` for `wParam`? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-subitemhittest : "

wParam
    Must be 0. **Windows Vista.** Should be -1 if the **iGroup** member of *lParam* is to be retrieved."

Comment: @JonathanPotter, How would i go about doing that? I am not familiar with WINE.

Comment: @VladFeinstein, My aim is to identify when the mouse is over a checkbox. I initially used `0` for `wParam` but I could not find a way to differentiate having the mouse over the left side of the first column header and having the mouse over the checkbox of the first row. So, out of curiosity, I decided to try `-1` for `wParam` and I could see a way to differentiate the two. The only thing that bothered me was the undocumented value. Thus, my inquiry. It looks like I drifted into undocumented territory.

Comment: Mouse over checkbox - you're looking for `LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, Yes. I am well aware of the `LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON` flag. That same flag is also present when the mouse is in the header control above the top checkbox. I have been looking for a way to differentiate that from when the mouse is actually over a checkbox and stumbled over the undocumented flag. Another (well-documented) approach would be to get the header control coordinates and compare the mouse position with those points.

Comment: You're overthinking this. The header doesn't need to come into it at all. Check if a valid item is returned, and if the `LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON` flag is set. You know you've got the checkbox.

Comment: I am testing this as I go and I can assure you that when the mouse is over the header control in the area where a checkbox might be (as if there was one above the first visible checkbox), the result of the `LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST` message is 0 (indicating the first row) and the `LVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON` flag is set.

Comment: I am confused as to why this question was closed and marked as opinion-based. As of today, I have not received any private feedback on the reason why it was closed. This is inconsistent with the guidelines provided on the [site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). My posts express observations, not opinions. If what I am doing is incorrect, it would be better to point out the error rather than to close the question and eliminate the opportunity for further feedback by others.